# How to compare two files in vxworks shell?

Tags: file, shell, vxworks

I have two files with the same size available on my target. I am just thinking, if they are really the same? How to check that in vxWorks shell? My files:

```
-> ls "/a0",1

Listing Directory /a0:
-rwxrwxrwx  1 0       0              2336692 Feb  1  1980 vxWorks
-rwxrwxrwx  1 0       0              2336692 Feb  1  1980 vxWorks2
value = 0 = 0x0
->
```

Answer (score 2):

Comparing two files in vxWorks shell is really simple. Use below calls to do that:

```
-> fd1=open("/a0/vxWorks",2,0)
New symbol "fd1" added to kernel symbol table.
fd1 = 0x8a4dfe0: value = 5 = 0x5
-> fd2=open("/a0/vxWorks2",2,0)
New symbol "fd2" added to kernel symbol table.
fd2 = 0x8a65fe0: value = 6 = 0x6
-> b1=malloc(2336692)
New symbol "b1" added to kernel symbol table.
b1 = 0x8a89fe0: value = 153153552 = 0x920f010
-> b2=malloc(2336692)
New symbol "b2" added to kernel symbol table.
b2 = 0x8a95fe0: value = 155490272 = 0x94497e0
-> read(fd1,b1,2336692)
value = 2336692 = 0x23a7b4 = pathCondense + 0x9c
-> read(fd2,b2,2336692)
value = 2336692 = 0x23a7b4 = pathCondense + 0x9c
-> strcmp(b1,b2)
value = 0 = 0x0
```

If the last call return '0', it means the files are the same.